# How many ways to choose 12 guest

Tags: combinatorics

Exercise 2.19 from Pavel Mladenović's ***Combinatorics***.

Peter has 12 relatives (five men and seven women), and his wife also has 12 relatives (five women and seven men). They do not have common relatives. They decide to invite 12 guests, six each of their relatives, such that there are six men and six women among the guests. How many ways can they choose 12 guests?

Will this be $12! * {12 \choose 6} * {12 \choose 6}$. Choose 6 men out of 12 total and choose 6 women out of 12 total?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terms show the number of independent ways to choose the relevant participants (given constraints).  You must sum over all these:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^5 \underbrace{ \overbrace{{5 \choose k}}^{men} \overbrace{{7 \choose 6-k}}^{women}}_{Peter~friends} \underbrace{ \overbrace{{7 \choose 6-k}}^{men} \overbrace{{5 \choose k}}^{women}}_{wife~friends} = 267,148.$$

Explanation example:  Suppose we choose exactly $k=2$ men from Peter's friends.  There are exactly ${5 \choose 2}$ ways to do that.  Given there are to be $6$ total friends from Peter chosen, there are exactly ${7 \choose 6-2 = 4}$ independent ways to choose the women.  There must be $4$ men chosen from the wife's friends; there are ${7 \choose 4}$ ways to do that.  Finally, there must be $k$ women chosen from the wife's friends.  There are ${5 \choose 2}$ ways to do that.

Now the number of Peter's men friends can be $0, \ldots , 5$ (and not $6$, as he only has $5$ male friends), so we must sum up each of these cases.

Clear?